# Transfer a variable between buttons in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I'm new to Excel VBA. And I have the following code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LR2 As Long
Dim cell2 As Range

'A MODIFIER
With Sheets("A")

    LR2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell2 In .Range("A5:A" & LR2)
        If cell2.Value = "" Then

        cell2.Value = TextBox1.Text
        Exit For

        End If
    Next cell2

    Label8.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 1).Text
    Label9.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 2).Text
    Label10.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 3).Text
    Label11.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 4).Text
    Label12.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 5).Text
    Label13.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 6).Text
End With
End Sub
```

Now I want to pass the variable cell2 to the other button :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    cell2.Offset(, 7).Value = TextBox2.Text
    cell2.Offset(, 19).Value = TextBox3.Text
End Sub
```

Kind Regards

Comment: What's supposed to happen if the user just clicks `CommandButton2`?  If you make cell2 a Global variable then other methods can use its value, but it's unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you for the response, actually the user should fill in two textboxes before clicking button 2. The values of these textboxes are allocated to two cells in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't agree with your methods but you could use a private variable.

```
Private cell2 As Range  '<~~ this is at the TOP of the page in the declarations area

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim LR2 As Long

    'A MODIFIER
    With Sheets("A")

        LR2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell2 In .Range("A5:A" & LR2)
            If cell2.Value = "" Then

            cell2.Value = TextBox1.Text
            Exit For

            End If
        Next cell2

        Label8.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 1).Text
        Label9.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 2).Text
        Label10.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 3).Text
        Label11.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 4).Text
        Label12.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 5).Text
        Label13.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 6).Text
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    cell2.Offset(, 7).Value = TextBox2.Text
    cell2.Offset(, 19).Value = TextBox3.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I mentioned before I'm new to VBA.Can you please tell me why my methods are unfavorable ? Thank you

Comment: Among other things, there is the possibility that a user will click button2 when cell2 is nothing. They could also click it when it has already been clicked previously. I cannot comment further as you have not adequately decribed **exactly** what you are trying to do.